# Print integer as character digits (no arrays/printf/etc...)

Tags: c, integer, character

I am attempting to print integers to the console in C with a few constraints, the most significant of which being that I may only write individual characters to the console as follows:

```
void my_char(char ch)
}
    write(1, &ch, 1);
}
```

Other constraints include NO predefined methods (printf, log, etc). No recursion. Lastly, I may NOT create an array.

So far I have come up with a method that prints the numbers out perfectly well... backwards.

```
int main()
{
    int i = -345320;
    my_int(i);
    return 0;
}

void my_int(int x)
{
    char *a;
    int n;

    if(x < 0)
    {
            x = x * -1;
            my_char('-');
    }

    while(x)
    {
            n = x % 10;
            a = (char*)&n;
            my_char(*a + 48);
            x /= 10;
    }
}
```

Are there other good ways to approach this or am I at least going in the right direction? I would ideally like to expand this to print an integer in any base I provide, but I need to start here.

I was playing with iterating a pointer over each Byte of the integer but I can't grasp how I would use those character values to re-create the integer.

Any advice is appreciated. I'd much rather receive some insight than just a code solution. I'd also love input on making it more lean.

Comment: Try recursion, and print the digits after the recursive step.

Comment: My mistake; I am avoiding recursion as well. Updated to mention this.

Comment: To make it leaner, you can get rid of n and a and just use this line in the while loop `my_char(x % 10 + '0');`.

Comment: Your code not only prints the number backwards but won't work for 0 or INT_MIN. (There is no positive version of INT_MIN on two's-complement machines.)

Comment: Here's an idea. Try using a variable that starts at one-billion (assuming 32-bit ints). Use that to pick off the numbers from most-significant on down.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. It prints the integer forwards.:

```
void my_int(int x)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int divFactor = 10;

    if(x==0)
    {
        my_char('0');
        return;
    }

    if(x < 0)
    {
            x = x * -1;
            my_char('-');
    }
    temp = x;
    while((temp /= 10) > 10) {divFactor *= 10;}

    for(;divFactor > 0;divFactor /= 10)
    {
        temp = x;
        temp /= divFactor;
        my_char(temp + '0');
        x -= divFactor * temp;
    }
    printf("\n done!");
}


int main()
{
    int i = -1234001;
    my_int(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest a break instead of a flag.

Comment: You're right on both counts. I fixed `12345` and changed my flag to a break.

Comment: And I bet you could move that inner while outside of the other loop. Calculate that number once and divide it by 10 each iteration of the main loop. You could also get rid of a and n and use '0' instead of 48.

Comment: +1, but you should get rid of a and n since you're not using them. And it's considered better style to use '0' instead of 48. Easier to read and more portable.

Comment: Right again. Edit #4. Also I fixed trailing zeros and made it cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general (ugly!) solution following your constraints. It uses the idea I gave in the comment above. It assumes 32-bit ints.

```
void my_int(int x) {
    int n = 1000000000;
    if (x == 0) {
        my_char('0');
        return;
    }
    if (x == INT_MIN) { // INT_MIN is in limits.h
        my_char('-'); my_char('2'); my_char('1');
        my_char('4'); my_char('7'); my_char('4');
        my_char('8'); my_char('3'); my_char('6');
        my_char('4'); my_char('8');
        return;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        x *= -1;
        my_char('-');
    }
    while (n > x) n /= 10;
    while (n != 0) {
        my_char(x / n % 10 + '0');
        n /= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually seems like a relatively robust solution. It needs to be modified to print trailing/internal 0's (easy modification) but it looks like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Good catch on INT_MIN check.

Comment: Fixed trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

```
void my_int(int x)
{
    int n;
    int copy;
    char digit;

    // handle 0
    if (!x)
    {
        my_char('0');
        return;
    }       

    // emit sign
    if(x < 0)
    {
        x = x * -1;
        my_char('-');
    }

    // count base-10 digits in x, store 10^n in n
    n = 1;
    copy = x/10;  // shorten loop by 1 iteration
    while (copy)
    {
        n *= 10;
        copy /= 10;
    }

    // 'n' is now a digit selector
    while (n)
    {
        digit = x/n;
        my_char(digit + '0'); // print the most significant digit
        x -= digit*n;  // remove the most significant digit from x
        n /= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like @ooga expressed this idea as a comment shortly before I posted my answer.   Note that I changed the type of 'n' to 'char'  (although, as ooga pointed out, you can do without it entirely.)

Comment: Still prints the number backwards though. :(

Comment: Certainly helps with the cleanliness, so thank you! I'm still stuck on an actual solution. I'm afraid there isn't going to be a method through segmenting the bytes, but I'm still pondering it.

Comment: OK, I revised my answer to account for backwards printing.   I don't have a compiler handy, so I didn't test.

Comment: Just changed 'n' to be int instead of char.